# Divergence of terms $\frac{n!z^n}{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I am interested in $\lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!z^n}{n^n}, z \in \mathcal{C} \cap |z| = e$.

After plotting the function, I can see that the terms $\frac{n!z^n}{n^n}$ get to infinity (probably) if $z = e$, but how to show this formally and for all complex $z$ satisfying the condition above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Stirling,
$\dfrac{n!z^n}{n^n}
\approx \dfrac{c\sqrt{n}(n/e)^nz^n}{n^n}
=c\sqrt{n}(z/e)^n
$.

This converges for
$|z| < e$
and diverges for
$|z| \gt e$.

Comment: you intended to write $|z|<e$, right ?

Comment: Indeedeedo I done did.

Answer (score 3):

You could also have considered
$$a_n=\frac{n!\,z^n}{n^n}\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n z=\frac z {\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n }$$ and  then
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac z e$$

Comment: but this says that for $|z| = e$, I would have the limit = 1. What does it tell me? If $|z| = e$, the limit diverges. How do I get this from the ratio limit?